# c# winform function trouble

Tags: c#, function, browser

i have some problems with my function, im tryng to make function for webbrowser so i can have more easy control on it

this is my webbrowser function

```
static void Web_Browser_Data(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
{
    global webBrowser1; // This didnt work

    webBrowser1.Navigate(Data_Array["WebSite_URL"]);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}
```

i try to include webBrowser1 via global ( global webBrowser1; ) like this is on php to include some external command but i see is not working ...

The error what im getting is
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.Form1.webBrowser1'

**Update:**
i make some changes to my function but i get some error what i really can`t find how to fix it ...

My new function:

```
private void Web_Browser_Data(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)

{
    using (new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs())
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(Data_Array["WebSite_URL"]);
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }
}
```

My command code what i call the function is this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Data_Array.Add("WebSite_URL", "http://www.google.com");

Web_Browser_Data(Data_Array);
```

i get this error:

'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

Comment: There are no global variables in c#.

Comment: Welcome back Matei Zoc. I like your new user name.

Answer (score 2):

PHP and C# are extremely different.

You need to make your function non-`static` so that it can access the fields in the class instance.